# Skobelev graviton-photon cross section diverges

Tags: gravity, scattering-cross-section, quantum-gravity

Skobelev calculated in 1975 the cross-section of graviton+photon to graviton +photon and the graviton+graviton to photon+photon. For the latter, he gave the integrated cross-section, but for the first, I suppose, he only provided the differential cross section:
$$ \dfrac{d\sigma}{d(\cos \theta)}=\dfrac{k^4 \omega^2}{64\pi}\dfrac{1+\cos^8(\theta/2)}{\sin^4(\theta/2)}$$
Obviously, this cross-section DIVERGES at angles zero or pi, so, how could this cross-section be understood? Is there any method that allowed us to give a finite value? How could we regularize this quantity? Maybe by residues in complex variable? 
Remark: It is curious for me that gg to photon+photon does not diverge but changing to graviton+photon to graviton+photon diverges.

Comment: This is way over my theoretical tools, but this is discussed in this link https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.4148 , in chapter 5 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need gravitons. Even simple [Rutherford scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutherford_scattering) has a similar “infrared” divergence. It is a hallmark of large-range forces.

See [scattering singularity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38139/scattering-singularity). As a comment by @dmckee elaborating on his answer explains,

“$\theta$ only equals zero in the limit where $b\rightarrow\infty$. The beam isn't that big (or if it is the scattering that you want to measure only dominates in a finite region), so the divergence can't be measured. To put it another way, to directly measure the forward cross-section you use a downstream detector which has a finite size which limits the range of $b$ (impact parameter) over which you integrate. The signal is always finite.”